# How can get custom attribute value in meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, checkbox, dom-events

How can get the value of "key" attribute which is checked?

Html Code:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="each-tab-1" key="some1" value="456">
<input type="checkbox" class="each-tab-1" key="some1" value="789">
<input type="checkbox" class="each-tab-1" key="some2" value="890">
<input type="checkbox" class="each-tab-1" key="some2" value="901">
<input type="checkbox" class="each-tab-1" key="some1" value="012">
```

JS code:

```
'click .action' : function(event, template){
    $("input[class^=each]:checked").each(function(){
        console.log(this.value);
        console.log(this.attr('key')); **// giving error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"**
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just wrap the bottom this with $(this)

```
$("input[class^=each]:checked").each(function(){
    console.log(this.value);
    console.log($(this).attr('key')); // giving error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"**
});
```